# Converting epoch time to GMT Date Time Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I am currently using moment js in my application and not able to figure out how to convert epoch time to GMT date time. Providing my code below:

```
click: (event) => {
   console.log(moment.utc(event.point.category).toDate());
}
```

`event.point.category` is providing epoch time which I want to convert to GMT date time object, but above code is converting it to local timezone date object.

For ex. **1606262400000** is getting converted to **Tue Nov 24 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)** instead of GMT date time which is **Wednesday, November 25, 2020 12:00:00 AM**

Comment: From moment documentation: `moment.utc(event.point.category).format()` does what you are expecting.
https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/

Comment: @ParikshithKedilayaM Thanks for your comment but format() provides output as string and I am looking for javascript date time object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the (UTC) offset (in minutes) of the client to correct time

```
click: (event) => {
  const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); 
  const targetTime = moment.utc(event.point.category).toDate();
  const offsetTime = new Date(targetTime.getTime() + offset * 60 * 1000);
  console.log(offsetTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe all that you are missing is a `toUTCString()`.

An epoch timestamp will be the same for **Tue Nov 24 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)** and **Wednesday, November 25, 2020 12:00:00 AM GMT**

```
click: (event) => {
   console.log(moment.utc(event.point.category).toDate().toUTCString());
}
```

To remain as a `Date` object, use `moment.utc().format()`

Comment: I tried as you suggested but .format() is returning the output as string "2020-11-25T00:00:00Z". I am looking for a GMT date time object.

Comment: @rahul In that case, I highly suggest you use other complementing libraries such as https://momentjs.com/timezone/ or https://moment.github.io/luxon/ to help. I personally use Luxon as essentially moment.js and moment-timezone packaged together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
click: (event) => {
   console.log(moment(moment.utc(event.point.category).toISOString()).utc());
}
```